# Migrating to GA4, but can't find the "import from universal analytics" button

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, universal-analytics

I have been using the universal analytics for years but google is pushing me to migrate it to GA4.
I'm trying to migrate to GA4 with my history universal analytics data but it sounds like impossible.

All articles write: there is a button for this, but when I go the Google Analytics 4 Admin --> select GA4 Property --> Setup Assistant --> Property Settings --> Set up conversions --> I can't find the "Import from Universal Analytics" although the other two buttons are there and I have connected the ga4 property to the universal analytics property.

What can I do to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well your GA4 property is just likely not connected to any UA properties. Or the connected UA property has no goals set up. [Here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/13342757)'s how to find out what you're connected to.

[Here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12938611)'s the connection process described.